# how to make Java Rand() output between a numberset

Tags: java, random, arraylist

So I need to output Random numbers between -50 and +50 using Java Standard Collections 
These are then to be input into an ArrayList and sorted first ascending and 2nd time descending.

The Input and Sorting I Know how to do, but How can I generate random numbers between -50 and 50, considering these have to be input by a for do loop, one-by-one into an ArrayList

N.B. this question was for an exam, so even though the for-do loop (as an iterative) causes overheads I still need to follow these guidelines.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What kind of "numbers" are you wanting? Integers? Doubles? (And for this sort of task, the `for` loop is just fine; it's the collections that will impose the overhead.)

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of java.util.Random?

Comment: Mike Samuel responded thanks all :). They are to be Integers originally so using nextInt(int n) should cover it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want integers, then [`Random.nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) will do it.

```
myRandom.nextInt(101) - 50
```

should produce a pseudo-rangom integer using a flat distribution in [-50, 50].

> ## public int nextInt(int n)
>
> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified range is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All n possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

Comment: @DodoSerebro, I edited my answer to quote the javadoc.  `randInt(101)` returns an integer in the range [0, 100], and the `... - 50` shifts that range to [-50, 50].

Answer (score 3):

You can generate random number within a range start with 0 like this :

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomInt=randomGenerator.nextInt(101); //This function generate number in range 0 to 100.
randomInt -= 50; //It will give you number between -50 to 50
```

Answer (score 0):

another way as well

to produce a random double :

```
Math.random()
```

to produce a random double less than 100 for example

```
Math.random()*100
```

you can cast the result to any numerical type yu want

you can produce a your result like this

```
double r = Math.random()*50
if(r % (int)(Math.random()*10 == 2){
    r = r*-1;
}
```

something like that